# What is the easiest way to swap occurrences of two strings in Vim?

Tags: vim, scripting, vi

What is the easiest way to replace all occurrences of `string_a` with `string_b` while at the same time changing anything that was already `string_b` into `string_a`? My current method is as follows:

```
:s/string_a/string_c/g  
:s/string_b/string_a/g  
:s/string_c/string_b/g
```

Although this works, it requires extra typing and seems inefficient. Does anybody know of a better way to do this?

Comment: You might (also) want to try this question on SuperUser.com.

Comment: That's a great question -- one would think this easy… I imagine one could write a function that accepts two parameters and goes through the three steps for you, but I'd also have expected to find such a function with a quick web search.

Comment: This approach would fail if your file contained "string_c" anywhere already.  It's fine if you're a human and can pick a word that you know isn't in your file, but it'd be more difficult to teach a function to guess a good intermediary word.  Better to do it in one pass.

Comment: @BrianCarper I think it can fail even if string_c doesn't appear in the text, e.g. if the text is the alphabet "abcde...", string_a is "bcd" and string_c is "aa".

Comment: [As Peter Rincker answered on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17556572/707111), the [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin now does this nicely too!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
:%s/\v(foo|bar)/\={'foo':'bar','bar':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

But that's too much typing, so I'd do this:

```
function! Mirror(dict)
    for [key, value] in items(a:dict)
        let a:dict[value] = key
    endfor
    return a:dict
endfunction

function! S(number)
    return submatch(a:number)
endfunction

:%s/\v(foo|bar)/\=Mirror({'foo':'bar'})[S(0)]/g
```

But that still requires typing `foo` and `bar` twice, so I'd do something like this:

```
function! SwapWords(dict, ...)
    let words = keys(a:dict) + values(a:dict)
    let words = map(words, 'escape(v:val, "|")')
    if(a:0 == 1)
        let delimiter = a:1
    else
        let delimiter = '/'
    endif
    let pattern = '\v(' . join(words, '|') . ')'
    exe '%s' . delimiter . pattern . delimiter
        \ . '\=' . string(Mirror(a:dict)) . '[S(0)]'
        \ . delimiter . 'g'
endfunction

:call SwapWords({'foo':'bar'})
```

If one of your words contains a `/`, you have to pass in a delimiter which you know none of your words contains, .e.g

```
:call SwapWords({'foo/bar':'foo/baz'}, '@')
```

This also has the benefit of being able to swap multiple pairs of words at once.

```
:call SwapWords({'foo':'bar', 'baz':'quux'})
```

Comment: This is great! My only issue is that it swaps the occurrences everywhere. Is there a way to pass the lines on which you want the swap to occur similar to how `:17,34s/foo/bar/g` will only substitute on lines 17 to 34?

Comment: @dsg Can be done by making two changes to SwapWords(). Put the keyword `range` after the `...)` on the first line, then replace `'%s'` near the end with `a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's'`. Then it'll take a range exactly like `:s` does.

Answer (score 17):

You can do this easily with Tim Pope's [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin

```
:%S/{transmit,receive}/{receive,transmit}
```

Comment: %S /{<Test>,<Foo>}/{<Foo>,<Test>}/g
When I try to swap whole words, it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: @JanNetherdrake If you want to use whole words then use Subvert's `w` flag. `:%S/{test,foo}/{foo,test}/gw`. See `:h abolish-search` for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I swap two words `skip` & `limit`:

```vim
%s/skip/xxxxx/g | %s/limit/skip/g | %s/xxxxx/limit/g
```

Pretty sure someone could turn it into a shorter command which accepts two arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The [swapstrings plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#SWAPSTRINGS) provides a handy command for this:

```
:SwapStrings string_a string_b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single command as shown in my code below:

```vim
:%s/\<\(string_a\|string_b\)\>/\=strpart("string_bstring_a", 8 * ("string_b" == submatch(0)), 8)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to swap 2 strings separated by space bar within one line.  One can use:

```
:'a,'bs/\(.*\s\)\(.*$\)/ \2 \1/g

where 'a,'b defines section where this command is applied
      .*\s specifies string from begin of the line until space bar (\s)
      .*$  specifies the section until the end of the line
      \2 \1  in substitution use first section 2 and then section 1
```