# Double quotes in single quotes and vice versa

Tags: regex, vim, quotes

Often I find myself inverting quotes:
**from double quotes `""` to single quotes `''`** and
**from single quotes `''` to double quotes `""`**.

I know there is a way to switch single quotes to double quotes:
`:%s/'\(\([^']*\)\)'/"\1"/g`

And a way to switch double quotes to single quotes:
`:%s/"\(\([^"]*\)\)"/'\1'/g`

but how do I do both operations ***together*** without including the first swapped quotes in the 2nd swapping?

Comment: Use a hash map for subst multiple words in a single command:   %s/\<\%(foo\|bar\|baz\)\>/\={'foo':'bar','bar':'baz','baz':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/gc  ..  Here foo -> bar, bar -> baz, baz -> foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no escaped quotes inside string literals and it is not needed to
ensure correct pairing of quotes, one can use the command

```
:%s/['"]/\="'\""[submatch(0)!='"']/g
```

Comment: `@ib, what do you mean with escaped quotes? Your regex works also on your own regex (with escaped quotes?) - btw tnx :)

Comment: @Remonn:  I mean quote escaping syntax in the text you operate on.  If you run these substitutions on, say, Vim-script string literals, then `"one\"two"` would be changed to `'one\'two'` which does not represent the same string as the original literal.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, when you want to swap `A` & `B` like this, you need an intermediate step where you replace `A` with something entirely different and very likely to be unique within the document, whether an unusual character or something longer and crazier like `|x-monkeyz-x|`.

You can then convert all the Bs to As, and finally all the `|x-monkeyz-x|` to Bs.

For example,

1. Replace all `'` with `!X!`
2. Replace all `"` with `'`
3. Replace all `!X!` with `"`

#### EDIT

This is better: [Easiest way to swap occurrences of two strings in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578549/easiest-way-to-swap-occurrences-of-two-strings-in-vim)

Answer (score 3):

I usually use an intermediate string like my name that's unlikely to appear in the text:

- Change single quote to UNLIKELY_STRING
- Change double quote to single quote
- Change UNLIKELY_STRING to double quote

Answer (score 2):

Use `\=`:

```
:%s/'\([^']*\)'/\='"'.tr(submatch(1), '"', "'").'"'/g
```

. This assumes that both characters only serve as quotes, but your initial code also does the same, except that my does not check for them being paired.

Answer (score 1):

As said by someone here:

```
:%s/"/*/g | %s/'/"/g | %s/*/'/g
```

This could be done by three commands separately.
Also by two commands:

```
:%s/'\|\("\)/"\1/g | %s/""/'/g
```