# Swap two strings simultaneously

Tags: regex, sed

How can i do in sed what `tr "ae" "ea"` does? I can't use a temporary string like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578549/easiest-way-to-swap-occurrences-of-two-strings-in-vim), because I don't know a string that's guaranteed to not appear in the text.

Maybe I could first escape all 'a', 'e' and '\' with a backslash, etc... or is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [transform (y) command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49);

```
sed 'y/ae/ea/'
```

> > echo aerodame | sed 'y/ae/ea/'
>   earodema

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing why I was downvoted for this answer. Sure sounds like an easier way to me...?

Comment: [late] probably because y/ must be static width, and will complain about it, however, tr, by default, though it does take static widths as well, does not complain about it and therefore can lead to subtle bugs if used interchangeably

Answer (score 3):

You got your answer but wrt your statement that "I can't use a temporary string like in this question, because I don't know a string that's guaranteed to not appear in the text." You can CREATE a string like that like this:

```
sed 's/@/@A/g; s/foo/@B/g; s/bar/foo/g; s/@B/bar/g; s/@A/@/g' file
```

The above converts all "@" characters to the string "@A" then swaps foo and bar by first converting "foo"s to "@Bs". At that point you can guarantee that there are no "@Bs" in your text because every original "@" now has an "A" after it courtesy of that first s//. The rest should be obvious.

This is a very useful technique when you need to do other operations on your files using some other command(s) and need some string that's guaranteed not to be in the input:

```
sed 's/@/@A/g' file | <commands using @B, @C, etc.> | sed 's/@A/@/g'
```

Obviously you need to ensure that whatever command(s) you use in the middle don't generate "@A"s (or whatever replacement string you choose) as part of their output!