# In VIM is there a regex (or any other shortcut) that will allow me to swap 2 words?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm looking for a regex that'll allow me to swap between two words. (Other vim shortcuts are also acceptable)

I have a long list:

```
   a.transmit
   b.receive
   c.receive
   d.transmit
```

I need every instance of transmit to be changed to receive, and every receive to be changed to transmit so it should read:

```
   a.receive
   b.transmit
   c.transmit
   d.receive
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an expression:

```
:%s/\(receive\|transmit\)/\=submatch(1) == 'receive' ? 'transmit' : 'receive'
```

It's pretty self-explanatory - if the matched group is `receive` the expression evalutes to `transmit`, otherwise to `receive`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this easily with Tim Pope's [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin

```
:%S/{transmit,receive}/{receive,transmit}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
:%s/\v(transmit|receive)/\={'transmit':'receive','receive':'transmit'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a single command, but if you're willing to use sed 3 times, you can do something along the lines of

```
:%s/transmit/temporaryholdervalue/g
:%s/receive/transmit/g
:%s/temporaryholdervalue/transmit/g
```

which should switch all the values.

Comment: The simplest solution, barring plugins.

Comment: Possibly, but not quite what the question wanted. jh314 and ThiefMaster I think both answered the question better.